# MySQL count the largest referral trail in one table

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following table that records which users refer which users to the site *(simplified for example)*:

```
| id    |            user_id |    friend_id |
|-------|--------------------|--------------|
| 1     |                1   |          2   |
| 2     |                2   |          3   |
| 3     |                3   |          4   |
| 4     |                10  |          15  |
```

How can I do a kind of recursive query to work out the longest referral trail?

So in the above instance user `1` would have a referral trail of `3` because the person they referred, referred someone and then the person they referred referred someone else...

This could easily get quite complicated but I only wish to run it very irregularly.

It might be better to do it as a php function but I'm struggling to get my head around it?

Comment: If user 1 referred user 2, and user 2 referred 3 and 4, then how long is the referral trail for user 1? 1 or 2? In other words: is it the distance of the referred persons that matter in the chain, or the number of people that have been referred under a branch?

Comment: You would need a `while` inside a `foreach`, the only way I see is to use php. It's  anyway going to be very stressful for your machine.

Comment: @Shadow Should always start from a user who hasn't been referred to the site to avoid branches

Comment: @Silver89 I know that and I asked sg different.

Comment: @Shadow So it would only be the count of how deep it went as opposed to the amount they referred, hopefully that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

So, basically you want to traverse tree graphs and determine which one of them is the longest. With your data structure where you store parent and child ids you can to do it with loops in stored procedure within mysql.

You could do the same thing from php as well, however, that would add the overhead of communication between php and the database in each loop, so I believe, that the stored procedure implementation is better.

[This site](https://www.artfulsoftware.com/mysqlbook/sampler/mysqled1ch20.html) gives a good overview of how graphs can be implemented and traveresed within mysql.

You have to modify ListReached() procedure within it to return the number of rows instead of the list. You can even change the procedure into a function that returns the number. I would also change the create table part to create temporary table.

Then use the max() to determine which are the longest pathes.

As agreed in the comments, call this function for only those user ids that were not referred.